# VBA: Use one Excel Sheet to Insert to and/or Update another

Tags: vba, excel, loops

*Sheet 1* holds a full list of the current state of work orders
*Sheet 2* holds recent changes to those work orders and any new work orders

Both sheets have the same format with data in columns A to L.

I need to use Sheet 2 to update the full list held in Sheet 1. Work orders have a unique identifier which is held in column A of each sheet.

In general terms:
Process each row of Sheet 2.
If a matching work order already exists in Sheet 1, update it.
If no matching work order exists in Sheet 1, add it as a new row in Sheet 1.

In column A is the work order number.

Comment: If you cannot figure out how to use `iferror(application.match(...))` then just copy all of sheet2 to the top of sheet1 and remove duplicates. This question has been asked and answered numerous times. Write some code and if you have problems, come back and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: This question isn't clearly worded. I think you want this: sheet1 holds the current state of all work orders, sheet2 holds new workorders and changes to existing ones. You therefore want to process those changes / additions and update sheet1 accordingly, where the identifier for each workorder is held in the first column.

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

There may be better ways to do this, and as @Jeeped said, this has probably been asked before (though I couldn't find it). Hopefully the following is what you need. I've included lots of comments to help you understand the code and modify it should you need to.

```
Sub ProcessDelta()

    'Define the worksheets
    Dim shtDelta As Worksheet
    Dim shtMaster As Worksheet
    Set shtDelta = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set shtMaster = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim intDeltaStartRow As Integer
    'I assume there is a header row in the Delta sheet, if not, set this to 1
    intDeltaStartRow = 2

    Dim intMaxEverWorkOrders As Integer
    'One of several ways to find the first blank row in the Master
    'sheet is to start somewhere beyond the data and move up
    'we use this later
    intMaxEverWorkOrders = 1000000

    Dim cellDeltaWorkOrder As Range
    'Work order from Delta to be processed
    Set cellDeltaWorkOrder = shtDelta.Cells(intDeltaStartRow, 1)

    'For the destination to which we copy
    Dim cellMasterWorkOrder As Range

    Dim boolNewWorkOrder As Boolean
    'Default to assume it's not a new workorder
    boolNewWorkOrder = False

    'We'll work from top to bottom in the Delta sheet. When the cell is blank we've finished
    While cellDeltaWorkOrder.Value <> ""

        'We're going to search for the "current" workorder from the Delta in the Master.
        'If it's not there, we'll get an error. So we use "On Error" to handle it
        On Error GoTo ErrorStep
        'If there is no error, after the following line cellMasterWorkOrder will be the cell containing the matching workorder
        Set cellMasterWorkOrder = shtMaster.Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(cellDeltaWorkOrder.Value, shtMaster.Cells(1, 1).EntireColumn, 0), 1) '

        'Reset error handling so any other errors are reported normally
        On Error GoTo 0

        'Check whether there was an error, if there was this was a new Workorder and needs to go at the end, so set the target cell accordingly
        If boolNewWorkOrder = True Then
            Set cellMasterWorkOrder = shtMaster.Cells(intMaxEverWorkOrders, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            boolNewWorkOrder = False 'reset this so we can check again for the next row to be processed
        End If

        'Output Row into Master
        cellMasterWorkOrder.EntireRow.Value = cellDeltaWorkOrder.EntireRow.Value

        'Move to next row in the Delta
        Set cellDeltaWorkOrder = cellDeltaWorkOrder.Offset(1, 0)
    Wend

    'We don't want to run the error step at this point so ..
    Exit Sub

ErrorStep:
    'It wasn't found, which throws an error, and so it needs added as a new row.
    boolNewWorkOrder = True
    Resume Next

End Sub
```